# Retain lowercase of consecutive words with \MFUnocap{word} and mfirstuc

Tags: capitalization, mfirstuc

When trying to retain certain words as lowercase using the `mfirstuc` package, I've run into the following problem. In the example below, I want to use `\capitalisewords` from the `mfirstuc` package to standardize capitalization among entrees, but I can't get the "al" in "et al." to be lower case even though I've specified as much using the `\MFUnocap{word}` arguments.

Any ideas what might cause this behavior and how to successfully retain "al" as lowercase with text like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
\MFUnocap{et}\MFUnocap{al} %DETERMINE WHICH WORDS STAY LOWERCASE

\capitalisewords{The fantabulous rap extravaganza, Deltron et al. (3030)}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\MFUnocap` macro considers punctuation as part of the word. Therefore, you should include `.` in the exception.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
\MFUnocap{et}\MFUnocap{al.} %DETERMINE WHICH WORDS STAY LOWERCASE

\capitalisewords{The fantabulous rap extravaganza, Deltron et al. (3030)}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This was it! Cheers. I thought I tried this, but I had a trailing parenthesis I also had to include.